# If block insead Each block in Svelte does not work

Tags: svelte

I am trying to render conditional elements/slots inside an #each block in svelte and I cannot figure out why it does not work. The following code does not work in Svelte:

```
<Menu>
  {#each items as item}
    <Item>
      {#if item.icon}
        <Icon slot="icon" icon={item.icon} />
      {/if}
      {#if item.label}
        <Label slot="label">{item.label}</Label>
      {/if}
    </Item>
  {/each}
</Menu>
```

There are a decent amount of moving parts so I wired up a small Repl to show this in action:

https://svelte.dev/repl/b089c2c379e9404596445c16311bd1b9?version=3.50.1

Comment: The question doesn't mention slots but they are used in the repl. Maybe this is more of a conditional slots content problem. A relevant issue: https://github.com/sveltejs/svelte/issues/5604

Comment: Your right! I will update the question.

Comment: Now I am really confused. Just opened my Repl and it's working randomly. I don't see that Svelte has updated since yesterday so I am not sure why this would randomly start working.

Comment: I think it's because you now have a default slot as well inside the Item - that wasn't there before?

Comment: I'm a fool, not sure how that got in there. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

i saw your question and was verry confused because it should just work.
I looked at your Repl and got it to work but not like you intended.
Instead of using components for the item and it's label and description, i just built it in one component like this :

```
<Menu>
    {#each items as item}
        <div style="background-color:gray;border-bottom:1px solid black;">
            {#if item.label}
                <div>
                    {item.label}
                </div>
            {/if}
            {#if item.description}
                <div>
                    {item.description}
                </div>
            {/if}
        </div>
    {/each}
</Menu>
```

It is not the prettiest answer but it works. I hope i ansered your question.